# Sysinternals Live unexpectedly slow?

Tags: windows-10, lag, sysinternals

I understand that the live version will inevitably be slower than a local copy.  However, considering my system specs and bandwidth, the amount of latency experienced seems far too disproportionate to be attributed to (solely) just that.

My system specs and speed test are as follows:
[image: System Info]
[image: Speed Test]
[image: OS Version]

The lag occurs at all times regardless of network load, and seems to be present for all utilities — even, in fact, just launching `explorer.exe` to the SysInternals UNC directory alone displays significant load time (and no, system is not under any significant load/stress).

The only thing left I can think of is perhaps the issue stems from server-side, but I don't want to simply make that assumption.  Is there any method to definitively determine the root cause (and hopefully implement a corrective/preventative action)?

Comment: If you mount a drive, e.g.:
`net use S: \\live.sysinternals.com@80\tools`
Do you find that more responsive?

Comment: I already have it mapped (exactly to `S:/`, no less), so I don't think that helps.  But I just noticed you have the port number defined, so let me try that.  Also, I just got a weird error right now trying to access it (configured as I had it before): [screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au6FcD8kvdA9gaZ4YazkJsxHPWv5KA?e=A4g68c)

Comment: So I went and disconnected the drive, remapped via your suggested `cmd` format,  and refreshed `explorer.exe`.  It was able to load without any error (which was kind of weird, I'd never seen that before) and while it wasn't exactly quick per-se — I ran `autoruns64.exe`, which is only 856KB in size — I do want to say it was much quicker than before, and there wasn't any longer periods of hanging where it felt like something was timing out before it'd finish loading.  I'm a litle concerned about about observation bias or other uncertainties still, but can you explain what the difference was in

Comment: the usage syntax?

Comment: Well given the theory that it will first consider the path as a UNC and wait timing out on those ports given the order it favours SMB/UNC over WebDAV. By explicitly setting the port I assume this ‘hint’ causes Windows to favour WebDAV for this connection and removed the wait incurred by the initial timeout.

Comment: Thanks!  I do want to wait a bit to see if any issues continue to occur or not, but seeing as no one else has contributed anything further, if you'd like to write this up as an answer and nothing else comes up in the interim, then I'll mark it as the answer in a few days time.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/support-for-unc-naming-and-mup has some useful information at the bottom of it regarding the order and why it was chosen that webclient (WebDAV) is last.

Answer (score 1):

*It has nothing to do with your system specs or bandwidth.*

UNC paths do not denote the protocol, so Windows attempts to connect through several protocols it knows. On most systems it uses SMB and WebDAV in that order.<sup>1</sup>

live.sysinternals.com is a HTTP/WebDAV server and doesn't speak SMB, but worse than that, it doesn't even *respond* to attempts to make an SMB connection.<sup>2</sup> When Windows attempts to connect first on TCP port 445 (modern SMB) and then port 139 (NetBIOS), it doesn't even receive a refusal – it just sits there waiting until the timeout counts down.

Several seconds later, the Windows network client gives up with SMB and attempts WebDAV (over port 80), which succeeds but by now the delay has occured. And if you access the server directly through a UNC path (not a mapped drive letter), this procedure likely repeats for every file operation as Windows doesn't seem to remember the server's type for long and just keeps retrying SMB again.

And there's also the issue that 1) the server may be physically far away from you, adding latency even to successful requests; 2) WebDAV itself is a verbose XML-based protocol with no batching. Both contribute to the total latency.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Historically, when Windows started using UNC paths, there were *many* LAN protocol suites. A short non-DNS name like `\\mypc` could have meant SMB/NetBIOS in no less than three different ways – over IPv4 or IPX or NBFrames – but it could also have been NetWare NCP, or AppleTalk AFP, or possibly VINES and DECnet and other weird stuff.)

<sup>2</sup> (Actually, even if the server was correctly configured to immediately refuse connections to unsupported ports, there would be another problem: some *ISPs* block connections to SMB-related ports, to reduce the potential for malware spread.)

Comment: While your answer was very informative, there was no suggested methods to mitigate the issue at hand?