# How to prevent Discord to start with System start-up?

Tags: windows-10, boot, discord

I have disabled Discord from starting-up at boot in **Discord settings**:

[image]

I have disabled Discord from starting-up at boot in **Task Manager**:

[image]

I have disabled Discord from starting-up at boot in **Windows settings**:

[image]

None of these have worked: Discord keeps starting-up at boot.

This question was already asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1560620/how-do-you-stop-discord-starting-up-with-windows) but in my case the accepted answer and solution is the first option I tried and does not work.

I have had this problem for years and I see others have had it as well:

- [5 years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/8gl73b/discord_boots_up_at_start_even_though_i_have_that/)
- [2 years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/llaoa4/discord_keeps_opening_on_startup_despite_turning/)
- [2 years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/ma1y1s/discord_keeps_opening_on_startup_even_though_i/)
- [10 months ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/veko2v/how_do_i_stop_discord_from_opening_on_startup/)

None of the solutions proposed have worked.

I have tried to post this same message on Discord reddit but for some reason my post was immediately removed:

[image]

Does anyone know what else I could do to prevent Discord from startin-up at boot?
Using Windows 10 22H2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Autoruns https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

"This utility, which has the most comprehensive knowledge of auto-starting locations of any startup monitor, shows you what programs are configured to run during system bootup or login, and when you start various built-in Windows applications like Internet Explorer, Explorer and media players. These programs and drivers include ones in your startup folder, Run, RunOnce, and other Registry keys. Autoruns reports Explorer shell extensions, toolbars, browser helper objects, Winlogon notifications, auto-start services, and much more. Autoruns goes way beyond other autostart utilities."

[image: Autoruns interface]